# using java script to check if string is numbers only

Tags: javascript, asp.net

using javascript to check if string is numbers only  this is what i have but its not running any suggestions would the appreciated thanks much in advance. also if it is a string of numbers only then all numbers after the first two digits should be masked.

```
 var start = function RenderRC(CodeOwner) {

     var pattern = /^\d+$/;
     var Rcode = CodeOwner.toString();

     if (Rcode.valueOf.match(pattern)) {
        if (Rcode.length > 2) {
            var newcode = Rcode.substr(0, 2) + Array(Rcode.length - 2 + 1).join("*");
            return newcode;
        }
     } else {
        return Rcode;
     }
 };
```

Comment: `Rcode.valueOf` is a function and doesn't have `match` method

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Answer (score 0):

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

See here: [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsNumeric(sText) {
    var Reg = new RegExp('^\\d+$');
    var Result = sText.match(Reg);
    if (Result)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `valueOf.` and it should run fine

```
if (Rcode.match(pattern))
...
```

Or add the parenthesis to it to actually call the function:

```
if (Rcode.valueOf().match(pattern))
...
```

But I don't think that function call is needed.